# Replace words in URL

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Pls help me in replacing words in urls/links for wordpress like  for example

if there is something in my article 

then this red is replaced by orange But this replacement should be in URL/Links only and if Red is written anywhere else in article , it should not be replaced/

Rules-
If red or Green or Pink Replace it by Orange
If Room or Kitchen or Dining replace it by House
if Breakfast or Lunch or DInner replace it by food

This change should be permanent is wordpress database
like this i have 10-15 rules that is to replaced.
I need a script for that for using in wordpress

Comment: ,share the code that you have tried

Comment: i have not tried anything yet.. i m a beginner...thats  why i need help

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="text_div">
       This div contains some text.
    </div>

    <script >
       $(".text_div").text(function () {
       return $(this).text().replace("contains", "hello everyone"); 
       });
    </script>

    use this code for find and replace on your page or post
```

Comment: If the content is not in <div> then what? like if i want to convert amazon tag "savedeal0a-21" with "goodpi-21" in any amazon link? like   www.amazon.in /dp/s1232432/?tag=avedeal0a-21 to www.amazon.in /dp/s1232432/?tag=goodpi-21               whenever savedeal0a-21 comes it should be replaced by goodpi-21

Comment: use java script to change this